# How to embed powershell script inside GO program to build a single binary

Tags: powershell, go, embed

I like to embed some powershell scripts in one Go binary. How can I embed them and execute the commands from GO.
Currently I got it by running an external script:

```
out,err := exec.Command("Powershell", "-file" , "C:\\test\\go\\my.ps1").Output()
if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)

}

fmt.Printf("Data from powershell script is: %s", out)
```

my.ps1 content:

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

I got a few more powershell scripts, I like to add the powershell scripts into my go binary file.
Have tryed a few things I did find on the internet but failed.

Comment: You can embed files in a Go binary, but to expose these to the host OS you'd need to copy the embedded assets back out to the filesystem (e.g. `/tmp`) - then you could initiate your `exec.Command`.

Answer (score 2):

Embed your asset:

```
import (
    _ "embed"
)

//go:embed my.ps1
var shellBody []byte
```

and then when you need the host OS to access this, surface it via a temp file:

```
tmp, err := ioutil.TempFile("/tmp", "powershell.*.ps1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer os.Remove(tmp.Name()) // clean-up when done


f, err := os.OpenFile(tmp.Name(), os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = f.Write(shellBody)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = f.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

then you can invoke `Powershell`:

```
out, err := exec.Command("Powershell", "-file" , tmp.Name()).Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to pass the embedded filename to the command (Powershell in this case) without doing the whole process of creating and writing to a temporary file?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The. Embedded files are in the go binary. To surface them, one has to proactively extract them via go code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use go1.16 and [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed), you should create a separated folder to save the embed file definitions, then use another function to return the string or byte[] file reference.

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "text/template"
)

var (
    // file.txt resides in a separated folder
    //go:embed file.txt
    myfile string
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("File %q\n", myfile)
}
```